# Bundle size in bytes

Tags: android, exception, bundle

**Is there any way to know the bundle size in bytes?** My point in asking this is I am saving parcelable object lists in my `bundle` on `onSaveInstanceState`.

I need to check if the bundle size is reached it's size limit and prevent any more data to get saved, and to prevent `TransactionTooLarge` exception to occur.

Comment: have u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47633002/how-to-examine-the-size-of-the-bundle-object-in-onsaveinstancestate

Comment: Can you edit the question and explain to us why below answer not works for you?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think easiest way for me is:

```
fun getBundleSizeInBytes(bundle : Bundle) : Int {
  val parcel = Parcel.obtain()
  parcel.writeValue(bundle)

  val bytes = parcel.marshall()
  parcel.recycle()

  return bytes.size
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Parcel class has dataSize() member, so the same result can be achieved without calling marshall():

```
int getBundleSizeInBytes(Bundle bundle) {
    Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
    int size;

    parcel.writeBundle(bundle);
    size = parcel.dataSize();
    parcel.recycle();

    return size;
}
```

Comment: this is in bytes

Answer (score 3):

Here's the same method provided by @Volodymyr Kononenko using Kotlin's extension function for those interested:

```
fun Bundle.bundleSizeInBytes(): Int {
    val parcel = Parcel.obtain()
    parcel.writeBundle(this)

    val size = parcel.dataSize()
    parcel.recycle()

    return size
}
```

In case you want the Bundle's size in Kilobytes instead of bytes

```
fun Bundle.bundleSizeInKilobytes(): Double {
    val parcel = Parcel.obtain()
    parcel.writeBundle(this)

    val size = parcel.dataSize().toDouble()/1000
    parcel.recycle()

    return size
}
```

BTW I wouldn't use writeValue() instead of writeBundle() as writeValue() adds extra 4 bytes to the size.