# How to examine the size of the Bundle object in onSaveInstanceState?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-bundle, onsaveinstancestate

I am using Android Studio 3.0.1 which allows to inspect the `Bundle` object in `onSaveInstanceState`:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

To do so add a breakpoint and once the debugger stops right click the `Bundle` object as shown in the screenshot and select "Show Bundle Objects..." from the context menu.

[image: Android Studio - Show Bundle Objects]

Then a window opens to list the `Bundle` objects as shown in this screenshot:

[image: Android Studio - Bundle objects]

Is there a way to find out **how much memory** the whole `Bundle` and it's children occupy? I want to identify the bigger chunks to optimize and avoid `TransactionTooLargeException` to be thrown on Android >= 7.

Something like Ubuntu **Disk Usage Analyzer** would be helpful - see screeshot:

[image: Disk Usage Analyzer]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also use this one :-

=> just pass the Bundle here

```
public int  getBundleSizeInBytes(Bundle bundle  ) {
            Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
            parcel.writeValue(bundle);
            byte[] bytes = parcel.marshall();
            parcel.recycle();
            return bytes.length;
}
```

Then use `android.text.format.Formatter.formatFileSize(activityContext, bytes)` to output nicely.

Answer (score 2):

The [TooLargeTool](https://github.com/guardian/toolargetool) is great for analysing bundle size when diagnosing TransactionTooLargeException.

Comment: Very useful to analyse bundle. Thank you.